# Generate a video from generated images

Tags: node.js, image, video, gif, mp4

I currently have an API route in nodeJS generating images from given inputs and then creating and returning a GIF from these images. I'm using [gifencoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifencoder) and [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) to do these operations.

I need to generate a mp4 video instead of a GIF for this route, so I've looked at different solutions, but none suited me:

- Converting the GIF to an mp4 with an ffmpeg, seems a little "heavy" and ffmepg need an image path on input to perform this.
- Using the image data from canvas to directly feed the [videoshow](https://github.com/h2non/videoshow) module, less heavy, but it still need images path.

I'd like to not save temporary images for this operation and having a straightforward process like :
"Informations > ImageData > Video".

Do you think it is doable ?

Comment: There are [Javascript-based MP4 (H.264 codec) encoders](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+h264+encoder) which take canvas content (imagedata) and then write it as an H.264 frame. See which one you like.

Comment: Oh great, this one doesn't came out during my searches ! I will try that right now, thank you !